# Не могу заставить работать gridсплинтер

Tags: c#, wpf

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

xaml:

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="179,52,0,0" Text="TextBox" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="66" Height="397"/>

        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="245,52,0,0" Text="TextBox" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="79" Height="397"/>


        <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="240,0,0,129" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="5"/>


    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Потому, что код надо писать руками и понимать что и как устроено в XAML. У вас сейчас все приколочено гвоздями к определенным позициям и если вы хоть немного измените размер, все, ваш элемент уже будет не там, где вы хотите. Например `Margin="240,0,0,129"`, что вы от этого ожидаете? Сделали сетку, задали ей колонки, поместили объекты нужные, указали им нужные колонки, задали отступы небольшие, позиционирование (право/лево/центр/верх/низ) и все, вот уже у вас будет готовый адаптивный дизайн с рабочим `GridSpliter`.

Comment: Я не успею переделать, есть вариант какой-нибудь без переделки?

Comment: Нет, ибо у вас нету ячеек у сетки и нет привязки у элементов к этой сетки. Вам надо сделать правильный Grid, задать ему `ColumnDefinitions` и/или `RowDefinitions`, затем правильно расположить `GridSplitter` (задав ему `Grid.Column` и/или `Grid.Row` и только тогда он заработает, НО у вас все элементы не привязаны к сетке, а значит они статично будут стоять на месте и их тоже надо менять, убирая `Margin` и задавая позицию в сетке.

Comment: Понял, спасибоп